# How to uninstall Coda plugins?

Tags: plugins, uninstallation, coda

I installed a coda plug-in and want to uninstall it, but am not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In the Finder browse to the **/Users/yourusername/Library/Application Support/Coda/Plug-ins** folder and remove the **.codaplugin** files you want to uninstall. That's it.

Oh, and be sure to replace *yourusername* with your Mac account name, usually it's *firstnamelastaname*.

Comment: There's going to have to be a little update to this answer, since Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) hides the library folder in yourusername directory.

Comment: in finder press CMD+SHIFT+G to access to Go To Folder... dialogue. Enter `~/Library/Application Support/Coda/Plug-ins` and press enter. If you are using Coda 2: replace Coda with Coda 2. Easy as that!

Comment: Or, these days, with Coda 2 `~/Library/Application Support/Coda 2/Plug-ins/`

Answer (score 3):

In addition the the accepted answer, you can just use `~/Library/Application Support/Coda/Plug-ins` and then you don't even need to know your username. The tilda will substitute for the logged in account.

Answer (score 3):

`Command + Shift + G` for "Go To Folder..."

Coda 1

```
~/Library/Application Support/Coda/Plug-ins
```

Coda 2

```
~/Library/Application Support/Coda 2/Plug-ins
```

Answer (score 2):

In OS X Lion+ you need to first make your Library folder visible:

http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/04/show-library-directory-in-mac-os-x-lion/

Answer (score 0):

As of Coda 2.5 it's possible to disable and uninstall plugins in from **Coda Menu> Preferences…**> Plugins tab[image]